# ¿Por qué a veces es reemplazado el BuildContext context, con un guion bajo ( _ ) en Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Estudiando e investigando sobre los diferentes manejadores de estados que utiliza flutter, me he topado que en los StreamBuilder o BlocBuilder, uno de los parámetros que piden es el BuildContext, pero en los ejemplos o videos se le pasa es un guion bajo y lo único que mencionan es "porque no es necesario" alguien podria darme una respuesta mas detallada de porque en estos Builders no es necesaro el BuildContext y en si que significa el guion bajo aqui, ya que hasta el momento el uso que le habia dado era para declarar que algo era privado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `_` es más decorativo que otra cosa.

Generalmente usamos esos valores, digo valores porque también puedes usar doble o triple, etc. `(_, __, ___)` , cuando no queremos o no vamos a usar esos parámetros.

Podría declarar :

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext _) {
     
     return Scaffold();

}
```

No significa que no reciba un parámetro, sino que no voy a usarlo, porque también podría usarlo con  `_.algúnMétodo()`.

Cuando tienes múltiples parámetros que no usarás, puedes usar doble o triple según corresponda.

Ejemplo:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext _, int __,  double ___) {
```

Es como si fuera un nombre de parámetro, pero que no piensas usar.

Si quieres más info avanzada de Flutter revisa mi canal de youtube (con el mismo username).

Aquí te dejo la documentación oficial, "por buenas prácticas" recomiendan usarlo cuando no piensas usar esos parámetros :

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-_-__-etc-for-unused-callback-parameters

Comment: Ah Diego! Claro que conozco tu canal y el grupo FB, gracias por la respuesta, jajaja había llegado a la misma conclusión al pararme a inspeccionar que tipo dato tomaba ese _ y justo pensé que era para indicar, "no se va a usar pero te mando eso para que no me.tires error" te agradezco la respuesta